# Ambiguous Match Found when adding object with EF

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am getting this ambiguous match found error all of the sudden. I can't figure out what is causing it. I am using MVC and Entity Famework. Any help would be appreciated it.

```
Ambiguous match found.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: Ambiguous match found.

Source Error: 

Line 355:                        //Save Object to DBLine 356:                        if (matchFound) { db.Entry(galleryFile).State = EntityState.Modified; }Line 357:                        else { db.GalleryItemFiles.Add(galleryFile); }Line 358:                        db.SaveChanges();Line 359:

Source File: c:\Users\holcombelr\SkyDrive\Public\Projects\UHV\Marketing\Marketing\Marketing\Areas\Intranet\Controllers\GalleryItemFileController.cs    Line: 357 

Stack Trace: 

[AmbiguousMatchException: Ambiguous match found.]   System.RuntimeType.GetPropertyImpl(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Type returnType, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers) +10615074   System.Type.GetProperty(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr) +30   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.PropertyOrField(Expression expression, String propertyOrFieldName) +47   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.CreateBaseGetter(Type declaringType, PropertyInfo propertyInfo) +79   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.PocoPropertyAccessorStrategy.GetNavigationPropertyValue(RelatedEnd relatedEnd) +148   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityWrapper`1.GetNavigationPropertyValue(RelatedEnd relatedEnd) +19   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.DetectChangesInRelationshipsOfSingleEntity() +200   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectChangesInNavigationProperties(IList`1 entries) +77   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectChanges() +81   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.DetectChanges() +19   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.DetectChanges(Boolean force) +34   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName) +74   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity) +108   System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity) +72   Marketing.Areas.Intranet.Controllers.GalleryItemFileController.MultiFileUpload(IEnumerable`1 uplMultipleFiles, String galleryItemID) in c:\Users\holcombelr\SkyDrive\Public\Projects\UHV\Marketing\Marketing\Marketing\Areas\Intranet\Controllers\GalleryItemFileController.cs:357   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +127   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3c() +50   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass45.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3e() +225   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass30.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__2f(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass28.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19() +26   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1b(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9514928   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18446
```

Here is the Method that the error occurs in. I marked the location of the error with the comment toward the bottom.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult MultiFileUpload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> uplMultipleFiles, string galleryItemID)
    {
        if (uplMultipleFiles != null && Common.IsNumeric(galleryItemID))
        {
            //Initialize Objects
            GalleryItem galleryItem;
            GalleryItemFile galleryFile = new GalleryItemFile();
            galleryItem = db.GalleryItems.Find(Convert.ToInt32(galleryItemID));

            //Check that we were able to get an GalleryItem
            if (galleryItem != null)
            {
                galleryFile.galleryItem = galleryItem;

                //Loop through the uploaded files
                foreach (var thisFile in uplMultipleFiles)
                {
                    //Check if we already have a file with the current extension
                    string extension = Path.GetExtension(thisFile.FileName);
                    var matchedGalleryFiles = (from g in galleryItem.GalleryItemFiles
                                                       where g.extension == extension
                                                       select g);

                    GalleryItemFile matchedGalleryFile = null;
                    if (matchedGalleryFiles.Any())
                    { 
                        matchedGalleryFile = matchedGalleryFiles.First();
                    }

                    bool matchFound = false;

                    if (matchedGalleryFile != null)
                    {
                        galleryFile = matchedGalleryFile;
                        matchFound = true;
                    }

                    //Create .jpg Thumbnail and Preview
                    if (extension.ToLower() == ".jpg")
                    {

                        string thumbnailFilename = galleryFile.galleryItem.imageName.Replace(" ", "-").Replace("'", "") + "-TH.jpg";
                        string previewFilename = galleryFile.galleryItem.imageName.Replace(" ", "-").Replace("'", "") + "-PR.jpg";

                        //setup filepath and save
                        //thisFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Areas/Gallery/Content/GalleryFiles"), thumbnailFilename));
                        if (System.IO.File.Exists(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Areas/Gallery/Content/GalleryFiles"), thumbnailFilename)))
                        { System.IO.File.Delete(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Areas/Gallery/Content/GalleryFiles"), thumbnailFilename)); }

                        if (System.IO.File.Exists(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Areas/Gallery/Content/GalleryFiles"), previewFilename)))
                        { System.IO.File.Delete(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Areas/Gallery/Content/GalleryFiles"), previewFilename)); }

                        FileTools.SaveFile(FileTools.ResizeImage(FileTools.StreamToImage(thisFile.InputStream), 150, 150), Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Areas/Gallery/Content/GalleryFiles"), thumbnailFilename));
                        FileTools.SaveFile(FileTools.ResizeImage(FileTools.StreamToImage(thisFile.InputStream), 600, 600), Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Areas/Gallery/Content/GalleryFiles"), previewFilename));
                    }


                    //Get FileType
                    var fileTypes = from f in db.GalleryFileTypes
                                    where f.extension == extension
                                    select f;

                    if (fileTypes.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        galleryFile.fileType = fileTypes.First();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fileTypes = from f in db.GalleryFileTypes
                                    where f.fileType.ToLower() == "other"
                                    select f;

                        galleryFile.fileType = fileTypes.First();
                    }


                    //setup filename
                    string filename = galleryFile.galleryItem.imageName + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmm-ss");
                    filename = filename.Replace(" ", "-").Replace("'", "") + Path.GetExtension(thisFile.FileName);

                    //setup filepath and save
                    string filepath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Areas/Gallery/Content/GalleryFiles"), filename);
                    thisFile.SaveAs(filepath);

                    //delete old file
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(galleryFile.filepath)))
                    { System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath(galleryFile.filepath)); }

                    //Give filename and filepath to object
                    galleryFile.filename = filename;
                    galleryFile.filepath = Path.Combine("~/Areas/Gallery/Content/GalleryFiles", filename);
                    galleryFile.extension = extension;

                    //Save Object to DB
                    if (matchFound) { db.Entry(galleryFile).State = EntityState.Modified; }
                    else { db.GalleryItemFiles.Add(galleryFile); } **// ERROR OCCURS HERE**
                    db.SaveChanges();

                }

                return Content("");
            }
            else { return Content("Error"); }
        }
        else
        {
            return Content("Error");
        }

    }
```

This is the GalleryItemFile class that it is trying to add the item too.

```
public class GalleryItemFile
{
    [Key]
    public int fileID { get; set; }

    public virtual GalleryItem galleryItem { get; set; }

    public virtual GalleryFileType fileType { get; set; }

    public string filename { get; set; }

    public string filepath { get; set; }

    public string extension { get; set; }

    public bool active { get; set; }

    public DateTime? createdOn { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string createdBy { get; set; }

    public string createdByUserName { get; set; }

    public DateTime? lastUpdatedOn { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string lastUpdatedBy { get; set; }

    public string lastUpdatedByUserName { get; set; }

    public int? width { get; set; }
    public int? height { get; set; }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the GalleryItem class as requested by Chris.

```
public class GalleryItem
{
    [Key]
    public int galleryItemID { get; set; }

    public string imageName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string description { get; set; }
    public List<string> tags { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string restrictions { get; set; }
    public DateTime? createdOn { get; set; }
    public string createdBy { get; set; }
    public string createdByUserName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? lastUpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public string lastUpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public string lastUpdatedByUserName { get; set; }

    public virtual List<GalleryItemFile> GalleryItemFiles { get; set; }

    public virtual List<GalleryTag> Tags { get; set; }

    public virtual GalleryCollection collection { get; set; }
    public virtual GalleryCategory category { get; set; }


    //public GalleryItem()
    //{
    //    this.GalleryItemFiles = new List<GalleryItemFile>();
    //}
}
```

Comment: This can occur if you have properties on a POCO that have the same name differentiated only by case. Don't see anything like that in `GalleryFileItem` but can you double-check your `GalleryItem` class?

Comment: This can unsurprisingly also occur if you have more than one property on a POCO with the exact same name (same case), e.g. through use of inheritance and the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be better as a comment, but I don't have the reputation for it...

The exception you're getting is related to reflection. It looks to me like what's going on is that this exception is being thrown when EF is trying to map between the GalleryItem proxy created by EF and your GalleryItem type. (EF creates a proxy to enable lazy loading, etc.) Your problem is probably related to that class and it would help if you posted the source for it. Here's a general description of the reflection GetProperty method (see the AmbiguousMatchException in the Exceptions section).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I posted the GalleryItem class. Interested in what you might see there.

Comment: I see what I did now. I had 2 tags properties in GalleryItem. I am giving you the credit because you pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem with EF. This link [AmbiguousMatchException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.ambiguousmatchexception(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> The exception that is thrown when binding to a member results in more
>   than one member matching the binding criteria. This class cannot be
>   inherited.

My code was simple. I used `object` type for `Id` property in base class `AEntity` but used `int` for `Person` entity. Using same types for `Id`s solved my case.

```
  [Table("Person")]
    public sealed partial class Person: AEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }


    [Serializable]
    public class AEntity : IEntity
    {
        public object Id { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IEntity
    {
        object Id { get; set; }
    }
```